# manage an actual-time based update of a table?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm a newbie and I'm building a database with a table which contains a list of jobs. Assuming the current time is between 8.00 and 8.30, an example is:

```
job    | start_time | end_time | status
-------|------------|----------|----------------
 A     |    8.00    |   8.30   |  processing 
 B     |    8.30    |   9.00   |  to do
 C     |    9.15    |   9.30   |  to do
```

as you can see the job A's status is 'processing'. It terminates at 8.30 and it's status should change to 'terminated' at that time. At 8.30 the first job ends and if there is a job starting at that time, it should be started, like job B that starts when job A ends. But there may not be a job starting when the last has finished, as the work C doesn't start when job B finishes.

Now, the problem is: how can I manage this actual-time based update of a table? I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: In my opinion that's not something a database should be responsible for controlling. There should be some kind of code project that reads the database and does actions based on what has been read. Both in doing the required action and updating the database values if needed.

Comment: You need a job scheduler and might be interested in [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.22/pgagent.html).